# Append id to URI - how to?

Tags: jquery, url

I do some jquery-toggle-action to an element and want to append a static id to the URL while it. So this is what I am doing:

```
$("#trigger").click(function () {
    $("#target").css({display: 'inline-block', transition: '0.5s'});
    var hash = $(this).attr("href","#added-to-the-uri");
    location.hash = hash;
});
```

But it doesn't generate: 
**xyz.html#added-to-the-uri** 
but this one
**xyz.html#[object Object]**

What do I need to edit for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
var hash = $(this).attr("href","#added-to-the-uri");
```

You are not setting the `#added-to-the-uri` to `hash` variable. You are setting the value of `$(this)`. The attr function returns the $(this) object.

You should add the anchor like this:

```
$("#trigger").click(function () {
  $("#target").css({display: 'inline-block', transition: '0.5s'});
  location.hash = 'added-to-the-uri';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply write like

```
location.hash = "#added-to-the-uri";
```